# GTK# application crashes when entry text is updated frequently. Memory Leakage?

Tags: c#, mono, gtk#

I am using Mono/GKT#/C# on Ubuntu to receive a UDP string from a flight simulator. The string consists of pilot inputs e.g. throttle setting, stick positon, etc...

What I need to do is to display the pilots inputs in different text boxes (entry:s) in my application.

I am using UDPClient in async mode and the simulator is streaming at 120Hz. Displaying the data works fine to begin with but doing many sudden movements on the joystick for a longer time causes the application crash with an error message saying SIGSEGV. However, if I do the same thing in a console application everything works fine. Also, if i chose not to display the data in the entry box it also does not crash. It seems like it is a memory leak issue with GTK#.

Do I need to dispose of the entry object, if so how should that be implemented? Or does the entry have a buffer that needs to be cleared from time to time? Or is there something else I am missing here?

A few simplified segments of the code:

```
public UdpClient client = new UdpClient(listenPort);
```

and

```
try
{
    client.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(receiver), null);
} catch (Exception e)
{ 
}
```

and

```
private void receiver(IAsyncResult res)
{
    IPEndPoint myIpEndPoint = new IPEndPoint(IPAddress.Any, listenPort);
    byte[] received = client.EndReceive(res, ref myIpEndPoint);

    string dataString = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(received);
    string[] dataArray = dataString.Split(',');
    entryThrottlePosition.Text=dataArray[4];  //The position in array with throttle position


    client.BeginReceive(new AsyncCallback(receiver), null);
}
```

All suggestions are welcome!

Comment: If it is a crash, show us the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

Forcing to update the entries on the main thread solved the problem.

```
Application.Invoke( delegate{

//Code

entryThrottlePosition.Text=dataArray[4];

});
```